# Is there a way to see if a value is like a value in a list in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like test is there is an item in a list of values that is LIKE the value I am giving it, in my case which tests (or i would like it to) if a name in a column ends in 'Street'.

In this case, the street names are a column like 'Greene Road', 'Pointer Street', 'Bleak Avenue'. I would like @Street to be true if a name ends in 'Street', but this code doesn't work.

```
IF ('%Street' IN ([Street Names]))
      @Street = True
```

This does not set @Street to True as I would like it to.

Comment: It's simple. SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'ABCCEEE' UNION SELECT 'abccddDD' etcc) src (Text) WHERE src.Text LIKE 'abc%'

Comment: Instead of SELECT , values subclause could be used: SELECT * FROM (value ('ABCCEEE'), ('abccddDD') ... ) src WHERE src.Text LIKE 'abc%'

Comment: Nope, you can't match a like with a list of values. You gotta spell it out one by one and use OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses (
    [Street Name] nvarchar(50), 
    [City] nvarchar(50), 
    [Country] nvarchar(50)
    );
INSERT INTO Addresses VALUES
('Oxford Street', 'London', 'United Kingdom'),
('Broadway', 'New York', 'United States'),
('Kurfürstendamm', 'Berlin', 'Germany');

declare @Street bit = 0;

SELECT @Street = 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM Addresses
           WHERE [Street Name] LIKE '%Street'
           );
SELECT @Street;

DROP TABLE Addresses;
```

Instead of `SELECT @Street =` , you can also use the following syntax:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM Addresses
           WHERE [Street Name] LIKE '%Street'
           )
    BEGIN
        SET @Street = 1;
    END
```

What you cannot do, is simply assign a value to a variable.  The `BEGIN` and `END` are optional, if there is only one statement involved.  My preference is to supply them always, as it removes one source of bugs!

Note also that SQL Server does not have a `boolean` type as such, but uses `bit` for the same purpose.

Comment: <pedantry> There is a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." You can't use a `bit` in quite the same way, e.g. `if @SomeBit then ...` isn't supported and must be written `if @SomeBit = 1 then ...`.</pedantry>

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I was looking for, thanks!